# "sign" function in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a function that returns +1 for positive numbers and -1 for negatives in Swift?

I looked through the *enormous* file that appears if you right-click->definitions on a typical function, but if it's in there I don't know it's name.

I did this:

```
(num < 0 ? -1 : 1)
```

But I'd rather use a built-in function if there is any--for self-documenting reasons at the minimum.

Comment: So what's interesting was that I *wasn't* going mad, there isn't really anything *exactly* like this. Very surprising.

Comment: All integer types have `signum` which has been around since iOS 8.0/macOS 10.10. That was 8 years ago so it should have been there when this question was asked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Swift 4

As has already been pointed out in [@Wil Shipley's Swift 4 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44993944/4573247), there is now a [`sign` property in the `FloatingPoint` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpointsign):

> **FloatingPointSign**
>
> The sign of a floating-point value.
>
> *Enumeration Cases*
>
> - case `minus` The sign for a negative value.
> - case `plus`  The sign for a positive value.

***However***, the comments to [the `sign` blueprint in the source code of `FloatingPoint`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/bc3189a2d265bf7728ea0cfeb55f032bfe5beaf1/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPoint.swift.gyb#L425) contains important information that is (yet?) not present in the generated docs:

> ```
> /// The sign of the floating-point value.
> ///
> /// The `sign` property is `.minus` if the value's signbit is set, and
> /// `.plus` otherwise. For example:
> ///
> ///     let x = -33.375
> ///     // x.sign == .minus
> ///
> /// Do not use this property to check whether a floating point value is
> /// negative. For a value `x`, the comparison `x.sign == .minus` is not
> /// necessarily the same as `x < 0`. In particular, `x.sign == .minus` if
> /// `x` is -0, and while `x < 0` is always `false` if `x` is NaN, `x.sign`
> /// could be either `.plus` or `.minus`.
> ```

emphasizing, *"... `.minus` if the value's signbit is set"* and *"Do not use this property to check whether a floating point value is negative"*.

Summa summarum: use the new `sign` property of the `FloatingPoint` protocol to actually check whether the value's signbit is set or not, but make sure to use some care if attempting to use this property to tell whether a number is negative or not.

```
var f: Float = 0.0

if case .minus = (-f).sign { print("A. f is negative!") }

f = -Float.nan

if f < 0 { print("B. f is negative!") }
if case .minus = f.sign { print("C. f is negative!") }

// A. f is negative!
// C. f is negative!
```

---

#### Swift 3

W.r.t. built-in functions, I think the closest you'll get is the `Foundation` method `copysign(_: Double, _: Double) -> Double`

```
let foo = -15.2
let sign = copysign(1.0, foo) // -1.0 (Double)
```

Naturally needing some type conversion in case you're not operating on a number of type `Double`.

However, I see no reason why not to create your own extension fit to your needs, especially for such a simple function as `sign` as they needn't get bloated, e.g.

```
extension IntegerType {
    func sign() -> Int {
        return (self < 0 ? -1 : 1)
    }
    /* or, use signature: func sign() -> Self */
}

extension FloatingPointType {
    func sign() -> Int {
        return (self < Self(0) ? -1 : 1)
    }
}
```

(here yielding `1` also for `0`, as in the example in your question).

---

*(Edit with regard to your comment below)*

An alternative solution to the above would be to define your own protocol with a default implementation of `sign()`, so that all types conforming to this protocol would have access to that `sign()` method.

```
protocol Signable {
    init()
    func <(lhs:Self, rhs:Self) -> Bool
}

extension Signable {
    func sign() -> Int {
        return (self < Self() ? -1 : 1)
    }
}

/* extend signed integer types to Signable */
extension Int: Signable { }    // already have < and init() functions, OK
extension Int8 : Signable { }  // ...
extension Int16 : Signable { }
extension Int32 : Signable { }
extension Int64 : Signable { }

/* extend floating point types to Signable */
extension Double : Signable { }
extension Float : Signable { }
extension CGFloat : Signable { }

/* example usage */
let foo = -4.2
let bar = 42

foo.sign() // -1 (Int)
bar.sign() // 1  (Int)
```

Comment: I think the extension is ultimately the way to go, I'm just utterly surprised such a thing doesn't already exist! In any event, is there any way to use generics for this? Or are the numeric types part of those "clusters" that aren't really generic?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Even a custom global `sign<T: SomeTypeConstraint>(arg: T)` would need to include a type constraint on `T` for a protocol that blueprints the less than function `<` as well as initialization to value we consider as "zero". Also, we would need to extend all types that we want to allow to use this function to the that very protocol, which would mean some amounts of code for all of Swift:s different int types. In this case, I think using an extension on `IntegerType` and `FloatingPointType` (as above) is a less painful option. I'll include, however, an example using the approach.

Answer (score 8):

You can use signum() if your value is an integer.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2886673-signum

Here is a code snippet to make it clear;

```
let negative: Int = -10
let zero: Int = 0
let positive: Int = 10

print(negative.signum()) // prints "-1"
print(zero.signum()) // prints "0"
print(positive.signum()) // prints "1"
```

Comment: This is actually the most accurate answer to the question.

Comment: This is available for all integer types but not for floating point types.

Answer (score 7):

The `simd` library has a sign method:

```
import simd

sign(-100.0) // returns -1
sign(100.0) // returns 1
sign(0.0) // returns 0
```

You get `simd` for free if you `import SpriteKit`.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift-4 floats have a new property:

```
public var sign: FloatingPointSign { get }
```

(However this only checks the sign bit, so it’ll fail for some cases like `-0` — see that accepted answer above.)

Comment: we heart Swift4

Comment: Make sure to note that the `sign` property describes the floating value's signbit, which is not necessarily the same as testing whether "the value is negative or not" (see details in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36272575/4573247)).

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
let result = signbit(number)
```

This will return 1 for negative numbers and 0 for positives.

```
let number = -1.0
print("\(signbit(number))")

1

let number = 1.0
print("\(signbit(number))")

0
```

Comment: this would return 0 or 1 would it not?

Comment: Note that this uses the sign bit for numbers represented by the floating point pattern, and hence only works for floating points type. For testing the sign of say an integer, you would need to cast to `Double` first, prior to applying this method.

Comment: @Masih but is the question asking -1 or 1 not 1 or 0. Obviously it can be simply changed but OP can already do that - he is looking for a foundation method that does so.

Answer (score 2):

`FloatingPointType` has a built-in computed variable but it returns a boolean. If you only need this operation on floats you can use an extension like this:

```
extension FloatingPointType {
    var signValue: Int {
        return isSignMinus ? -1 : 1
    }
}
```

However, I believe the best approach would be to extend the `SignedNumberType` protocol.

```
extension SignedNumberType {
    var signValue: Int {
        return (self >= -self) ? 1 : -1
    }
}
```

If you want 0 to return -1 then just change `>=` to `>`.

Test cases:

```
print(3.0.signValue)
print(0.signValue)
print(-3.0.signValue)
```

Comment: `0.signValue` should probably return `0`

Comment: Quite possibly, though I imagine it depends on your specific use case. I was implementing the behavior consistent with his example shown above.

Comment: @Clashsoft nah, overwhelmingly programmers understand that something like "signValue" will return a 1 on zero, that it is "boolean like" not "ternary like". (Note that the word "sign" is very boolean.) The reason is the most typical use case is along the lines if .. something .. value = 17 * x.signValue.  ie, you're making a new value of some certain magnitude, "with the sign of the thing in question".

Comment: @Clashsoft in fairness, signum does what you say, but that's why signum is stupid, confusing, and banned in all working code bases.  (In algorithms where you need that, I've seen it renamed to something like "minusOneZeroOrOne" you know?)

Comment: Kevin, one point. I never return an int in such a utility, as, everything can go to hell with swift's implicit typing stuff.  IMO if you're working with CGFloats you want a CGFloat, if working with Float, you want a Float, if working with Int, you want an Int, etc. (Indeed I often name 'em something like ".signedOneCGFloat" and so on, so that there can be no mistake, as there can't be any mistakes in code.)

Answer (score 0):

Since copysign cannot be used over Integer I'm using this extension:

```
extension Comparable where Self: SignedNumber {

    var sign: Int {
        guard self != -self else {
            return 0
        }
        return self > -self ? 1 : -1
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both return and argument types should be same then this generic functions solve it:

```
func sign<T: FloatingPoint>(_ num: T) -> T {
    num < 0 ? T(-1) : T(1)
}

func sign<T: BinaryInteger>(_ num: T) -> T {
    num < 0 ? T(-1) : T(1)
}
```

Both can be defined together because Swift compiler able to select and inline the right function in compile time.

Examples:

```
print(sign(-1.23)) // -1.0
print(sign(0)) // 0
print(sign(1 as UInt8)) // 1

print(type(of: sign(-1.23))) // Double
print(type(of: sign(0))) // Int
print(type(of: sign(1 as UInt8))) // UInt8
```

Answer (score -2):

#### The real-world, working codebase, seen-everywhere, approach.

For what it's worth ...

Every real-world app codebase I have ever seen, has something like this in the utility files.

The comment block I have added fully explains the thinking.

```
extension CGFloat {
    
    ///Precisely as it says, return a CGFloat "one, signed". Return the sign of
    ///the number, expressed as either +1 or -1. As everyone knows, never use
    ///`.sign` in a working codebase, ever, for any reason, as it's broken by
    ///being stupidly-named. As everyone knows, never use `.signum` in a working
    ///codebase, ever, for any reason, as it's broken by being stupidly-named.
    var oneSigned: CGFloat {
        return (self < 0.0) ? -1.0 : 1.0
    }
}
```

Don't forget that code which is not self-documenting: is broken and unusable.

Every variable name in all code, not to mention call names, has to be *absolutely* non-misunderstanable.

There should never be a case, where even one programmer on the team, for a split-second has to think "what does this do" and this is incredibly true when you're dealing with a common source of unity errors in algorithms.

Indeed as mentioned in a comment somewhere, I've often seen that looking like this:

```
extension CGFloat {
        var oneSignedCGFloat: CGFloat {
            return (self < 0.0) ? -1.0 : 1.0
        }
    }
extension Float {
        var oneSignedFloat: Float {
            return (self < 0.0) ? -1.0 : 1.0
        }
    }
```

... so that there is **absolutely no possibility** of a mistake in terms of type.

In the extremely rare case where you need a ternary in an algorithm (which anyway basically means your algorithm is poorly-thought out), I would name it **EXTREMELY** specifically, such as

```
extension CGFloat {
        var minusOneZeroOrOneBeAwareThisIsTernary: CGFloat {
            return ... -1, 0 or 1
        }
    }
```

FWIW.